# Thoughts Regarding ALGANT

Tags: soft-question, career-development

Apologies if this type of question does not belong on the Math StackExchange page. Just let me know, and I will move it.

I have been browsing math graduate programs to pursue after completing my undergraduate degree. Overall I would say that my interests lay in algebraic geometry. While browsing programs, I came across an exciting master's program called [Algebra, Geometry and Number Theory (ALGANT)](https://algant.eu/index.php). This program enables students to complete a master's by attending a minimum of two universities.

I tried to find people's opinions on the program, but with no luck. There are no discussion threads about the program, and the two professors I asked said they had never heard about it.

This makes me doubt the program's quality, as a strong program would have people talking about it. But at the same time, I recognize that the program has had around 200 graduates, so it makes sense that the program is not well known.

---

My questions are as follows: Have you heard of the ALGANT program? If so, do you believe it's a good program?

Comment: I had never heard of it but it looks legitimate. Have you discussed this with your advisor or any of your math instructors? You can also look into their accreditation and research the backgrounds of their faculty.

Comment: @JohnDouma I've asked two professors I know, and neither has heard about it. That said, I will ask one more professor who studied geometry in France. With so many universities/professors taking part in this program, it might be hard to describe the program as just good/bad.